# Seeming error in Visual C++ 2017 ( ver 15.9.3 )

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Have the following code which compiles and runs fine in Visual C++ 2013, and the C++14 standard on http://cpp.sh.  However, on Visual C++ 2017 ( ver 15.9.3 ), it gives an error message... which is maybe a bug?

Code is:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<long> v1 = {1}, v2 = {9};

    swap<vector<long>>(v1, v2);

    cout << "v1.front(): " << v1.front() << endl;
    cout << "v2.front(): " << v2.front() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I should note that if I comment out swap() function, then it compiles and runs ok. The error messages are all resulting from the call to swap().

Error messages are:

maptest.cpp

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2048): error C2039: '_Alloc': is not a member of 'std::vector<long,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=long
        ]
maptest.cpp(9): note: see declaration of 'std::vector<long,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=long
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2096): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Vb_iter_base<_Alvbase_wrapped>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Alvbase_wrapped=std::vector<long,std::allocator<long>>
        ]
maptest.cpp(11): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Vb_reference<std::vector<long,std::allocator<_Ty>>>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=long
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2048): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Alloc'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2049): error C2065: '_Alvbase': undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2049): error C2923: 'std::allocator_traits': '_Alvbase' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Alloc'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2049): error C2955: 'std::allocator_traits': use of class template requires template argument list
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xmemory0(903): note: see declaration of 'std::allocator_traits'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2049): error C2039: 'size_type': is not a member of 'std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2049): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'size_type'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2050): error C2065: '_Alvbase': undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2050): error C2923: 'std::allocator_traits': '_Alvbase' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Alloc'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2050): error C2955: 'std::allocator_traits': use of class template requires template argument list
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xmemory0(903): note: see declaration of 'std::allocator_traits'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2050): error C2039: 'difference_type': is not a member of 'std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2050): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'difference_type'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2051): error C2065: '_Alvbase': undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2051): error C2923: 'std::_Rebind_alloc_t': '_Alvbase' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Alloc'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2058): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Sizet'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2065): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Sizet'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2072): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Sizet'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2089): error C3646: '_Myoff': unknown override specifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector(2089): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::swap` is [overloaded for `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap2) as

```
template< class T, class Alloc>
void swap(vector<T,Alloc>& lhs, vector<T,Alloc>& rhs);
```

The correct template arguments for your given vector would be `T=long, Alloc = std::allocator<long>`. The proper way to call `swap` (or almost any other templated function) on an `std::vector` is to simply drop the explicit template argument specification altogether and let template argument deduction do its work.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I should have tried that. It was a simplification of code I inherited. I wondered myself about the explicit template arguments...should have tried without them. Thanks.